# Installing JRE on Debian Docker Image

Tags: java, docker

When I attempt to build this dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /app/server .

# Install Java (for file disarmament below) and the ClamAV virus scanner (https://www.clamav.net/)
# Separated installs to troubleshoot package installation errors involving JRE
RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install default-jre -y
RUN apt-get install clamav -y 
RUN apt-get install clamav-daemon -y
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install default-jre -y" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

This error does not turn up on any Google search and apparently I am the first human to ever encounter it. What is going on here?

```
#0 45.53 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.14.6-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.53    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:3a3617c8874085a476df2c7a0dbd45325b2b07ecf21140fb857cd6b58aa9b4d4
#0 45.53     - MD5Sum:0cb152d995f25e1830193dd30a8d99ca [weak]
#0 45.53     - Filesize:199872 [weak]
#0 45.53    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:fc4560303b7773470818406c6df9c7ecd5c9fd5811db0a0697328680552547f3
#0 45.53     - MD5Sum:b7b05ac333b6d71791ee6f94f65e6c51 [weak]
#0 45.53     - Filesize:199872 [weak]
#0 45.53    Last modification reported: Wed, 08 Feb 2023 17:56:30 +0000
#0 45.53 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gtk%2b3.0/gtk-update-icon-cache_3.24.37-2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.53    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:4de5413b9a3c4225a6f72e6fe4e643e24dfd4f1063fd043c38cd10d7bd71079f
#0 45.53     - MD5Sum:746163a590fc2ce9eb76f363d5a70215 [weak]
#0 45.53     - Filesize:43300 [weak]
#0 45.53    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:35e21170dc32816506e6983d5be94cf83d7fec2bd71ceae6c27c3ae560f72ff7
#0 45.53     - MD5Sum:bd2727e362a437ee2b18a269c3adf631 [weak]
#0 45.53     - Filesize:43300 [weak]
#0 45.53    Last modification reported: Wed, 08 Mar 2023 19:42:47 +0000
#0 45.53 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-common-data_0.8-10_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.53    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:24b64db6a76378987478a9363e88cd8a50a0200e2cdfa316a35107f3faae39bd
#0 45.53     - MD5Sum:3e23f713d5520a28314cae30362be535 [weak]
#0 45.53     - Filesize:106832 [weak]
#0 45.53    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:dc3ad12f173b83bb4e7204f91f1f20033f5d5a5d787d0f5c5e7c8adb4d01f3b0
#0 45.53     - MD5Sum:5fe07c25452f9fc634dc10bb6f69fd4b [weak]
#0 45.53     - Filesize:106832 [weak]
#0 45.53    Last modification reported: Wed, 19 Apr 2023 12:43:53 +0000
#0 45.53 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-17/openjdk-17-jre-headless_17.0.7%2b7-1%7edeb12u1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.53    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:bc8baf2a73e905b2fc939d8b7d982ee2f7d58499373f9c8b2f9b672db70b43b4
#0 45.53     - Filesize:43744788 [weak]
#0 45.53    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:69addb3501e8771ec6d9814d39dc783dc1f3cf1e29a94aa551651f64893f5e8f
#0 45.53     - Filesize:43744788 [weak]
#0 45.53    Last modification reported: Mon, 12 Jun 2023 01:44:38 +0000
#0 45.53 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pixman/libpixman-1-0_0.42.2-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.53    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:9ed75ef81b6b1eba9e1357f8b0ce01d31112b0e07b2b685bee2cf627a8932892
#0 45.53     - MD5Sum:65313d4125a22ed2ca198dee3fdabdd1 [weak]
#0 45.53     - Filesize:545588 [weak]
#0 45.53    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.53     - SHA256:e134aa813d3a03730b57e8fbbfd1c873cec948c985bf5c8d5bd3cdcf96b8a1cc
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:d8c7dd5f798079c14ff8831f1a5d897f [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:545588 [weak]
#0 45.54    Last modification reported: Fri, 11 Nov 2022 13:42:31 +0000
#0 45.54 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pango1.0/libpango-1.0-0_1.50.12%2bds-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.54    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:851720de07441ae6bb6a7f51fc0f2edb4db7aa6f25b5bf1bf7b72dcab8947b7f
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:5c9051d5bf37660b1dac92e5410033da [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:211788 [weak]
#0 45.54    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:13f9a2915d3a966f9b80a1bac6dd1921140c8329e2c05e249aa052e14b9fb485
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:238b80bdf52e65e22020b6c9cd556167 [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:211788 [weak]
#0 45.54    Last modification reported: Thu, 15 Dec 2022 15:13:21 +0000
#0 45.54 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gtk%2b2.0/libgtk2.0-0_2.24.33-2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.54    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:365a7d48ad366b743b3f14f232cee199f46752b759871ab9cc7c7ce211b2fd75
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:d0751e1b784cb201e05cb4816d87f291 [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:1854976 [weak]
#0 45.54    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:c9192da5f212a2276678bdcff9f956587083240e5e3284e1236e2edab6149ad2
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:20c7fc0b602b1c9d6430d2ba2d610bcc [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:1854976 [weak]
#0 45.54    Last modification reported: Wed, 19 May 2021 20:12:31 +0000
#0 45.54 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxcb/libxcb-sync1_1.15-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.54    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:3366ce715220d38dd0148b78a8e738137bade25ef7eec0698850c6f66800844f
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:45281b9c1baf063fdb3123554011b77f [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:108692 [weak]
#0 45.54    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:5dd42a1b6623ac3bf895330c2364a66862db28fe50371c8bc1f4eeca6f83064e
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:7c92cf95e552fd54a8dc6eba16ac613b [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:108692 [weak]
#0 45.54    Last modification reported: Thu, 04 Aug 2022 06:55:38 +0000
#0 45.54 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpciaccess/libpciaccess0_0.17-2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.54    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:4025f3608cf431c163efb94fdc553e7b93e16b8f0d741ea87762e19025ffc80e
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:2acb508197bd0ab698352ceedc624980 [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:51384 [weak]
#0 45.54    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:0757d7f3e4941f7654918b343a586547e1528575ebc9b6c532a58a9b450521ca
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:428eda30e500d741fed80c8c440e7407 [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:51384 [weak]
#0 45.54    Last modification reported: Tue, 08 Nov 2022 12:13:54 +0000
#0 45.54 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.3.6-1%2bdeb12u1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.54    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:2c3fbfb89a8eadf6a82836b2443bc4d9578cb83847daf37cf6ab6074daf4fcda
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:b5a473c71f867037cb86e61023b44faf [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:7238788 [weak]
#0 45.54    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:74ce14e7c6d5cc9462aba8826d54f0bca4a8e0cca8eb35887b924edc00e705ac
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:bfd2d56c76da433e337859ef63930ce5 [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:7238788 [weak]
#0 45.54    Last modification reported: Wed, 22 Mar 2023 21:12:33 +0000
#0 45.54 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libf/libfontenc/libfontenc1_1.1.4-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.54    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:1d0aa6ea16a34a8de1ea170360c4cb699f3239aeddb292df2d2c4eb6e835de4b
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:051b4a70f65185a7358a58b06c770afd [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:24328 [weak]
#0 45.54    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:35c37a81c9ca311ada8cb239a87559a17ae0007c295dd699719222468431e7ef
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:b202d372a0e6db50b5ce588540556556 [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:24328 [weak]
#0 45.54    Last modification reported: Thu, 24 Sep 2020 09:44:16 +0000
#0 45.54 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxaw/libxaw7_1.0.14-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
#0 45.54    Hashes of expected file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:b208ae00c4ce66f0ef59a23ddaf9f9a84127c412e9f10a3817e34a095be6b72a
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:cfa4864645f71c58b062bef9de70a0e9 [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:201436 [weak]
#0 45.54    Hashes of received file:
#0 45.54     - SHA256:e8dab5814bfb070fe5f99c554dbf0b8d68fe554004cd30c857a33e31e43312c6
#0 45.54     - MD5Sum:a8c00b3672521f4debf9f08a9038106d [weak]
#0 45.54     - Filesize:201436 [weak]
#0 45.54    Last modification reported: Fri, 04 Mar 2022 15:26:34 +0000
#0 45.54 E: Aborting install.
```

```
#0 14.30 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
Dockerfile:40
--------------------
  38 |     RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
  39 |     RUN apt-get update -qq
  40 | >>> RUN apt-get install default-jre -y
  41 |     RUN apt-get install clamav -y 
  42 |     RUN apt-get install clamav-daemon -y
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install default-jre -y" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Comment: Don't know much about Docker but you'd have to run that as root or with `sudo` wouldn't you?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue: https://gist.github.com/b-enoit-be/e8c71b86d353ba93cf842d21788b8160. Could you try running your build with `docker build --progress=plain .` and share the resulting output, or at least the last lines of it?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the complete error?  A Docker container only runs a single process, so if it's running the Go application it's probably not running ClamAV or whatever you need the JRE for.  It's also important to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single command to avoid some layer-caching problems, and it will be faster if you `apt-get install` multiple packages in a single command.

Comment: ^-- That's probably the issue as my test was indeed doing `update && install`

Comment: @g00se no you don't have to run sudo in Docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze I split up the commands as I mention to troubleshoot this issue, it was in that format but I changed it in order to sort out which part or package was failing. Either way it gets the error. I posted the full error but it isn't all that helpful.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't know which archives it can't find but apt-get update runs regardless if it's a separate command or not.

Comment: Guessing there is no answer to this.

Comment: From the error message, you could be hitting this issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/160179

Comment: I run into the issue repeatedly with multiple packages so yes, you're probably right, because it doesn't happen when I connect to DC via VPN from my country.